# Copyfile and clusters reservation for Windows

Tags: windows

What is the OS (XP, Vista, Win7) behavior for copying files (with `CopyFile`) ?

When does it reserve clusters to copy to? which of the following ?

1. it reserves **all** destination clusters **before** starting to copy
2. it reserves **some** clusters, **then copy** a file **portion** to
   these clusters, **then**, reserves **additional** clusters, **then
   copy** a new file **portion** to these new reserved     clusters,
   etc.

Comment: It's easy enough for you to check this yourself. I expect option 2. If you want the OS to check for available space first then SHFileOperation should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy operation used by Explorer and cmd.exe reserves most of the disk space immediately, at least on my Windows 7 32-bit, as you can see by watching the free space on the volume.  To the best of my recollection this behaviour has been the same in all versions of Windows since at least NT 4.

However, there are several caveats:

- Explorer and cmd.exe don't (necessarily) use CopyFile.
- This behaviour might be different in different versions of Windows, or depending on circumstances.
- It might be only *most* of the destination clusters, for example it might sometimes needs to expand the MFT to complete the operation; I don't think this is likely, but I can't rule it out.

My recommendation:

If a slim possibility of the occasional failure is acceptable, test CopyFile and if it behaves as expected go ahead and use it.

If it isn't, consider doing the copy yourself.  Unfortunately that last caveat might apply even then, but as I said I think it's probably not a significant risk.

You need to be prepared to cope with an unexpected failure either way since hardware faults, or perhaps even file system corruption, could cause the copy to fail part way through.